# How can I auto-login users after registration with WP-Members?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently using the WP-Members plugin. I want newly registered members to be automatically logged in after they register. Can I achieve this functionality using a built-in hook or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

Yup! This is a hook that will do that:

> ```
> add_action('wpmem_post_register_data', 'my_registration_hook', 1);
>
> function my_registration_hook($fields) {
>   $user_login = $fields[username];
>   $user_id = $fields[ID];
>
>   wp_set_current_user($user_id);
>   wp_set_auth_cookie($user_login);
>   do_action('wp_login', $user_login);
>
>   wp_set_current_user($fields[ID]);
> }
> ```

Retrieved from [WP-Members: Automatically login after registration](https://danny.gg/2013/05/16/wp-members-automatically-login-after-registration/) - Danny Battison, May 16, 2013

This was written for WP-Members v2.8.2